# Android API 21 ignores layout_marginEnd and uses layout_marginRight instead in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, margins

Here is my EditText.
My issue is that Android ignores the layout_marginEnd in Lollipop and above
and uses layout_marginRight instead.
See two screenshots below:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/foo_count_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foo_container"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:hint="@string/foo_default_value"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"/>
```

[image]

As can be seen, in API 21 (left) the margin is 100dp, taken from layout_marginRight and not layout_marginEnd.

**Edit:
@ErnirErlingsson Nailed it: Need to enable android:supportsRtl in the manifest in order to use layout_marginEnd instead of layout_marginRight.
Thanks.**

**Edit 2:
Note however that in API 17 (right screenshot) the right margin is taken from layout_marginEnd while the android:supportsRtl is false.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One replaces the other, if you decide to support RTL now or in the future you should always use marginStart and marginEnd **instead** of using marginRight and marginLeft, otherwise you are fine with the latter.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL

According to the corresponding [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) RTL support should be disabled per default and therefore the left/right margins should be used. To my knowledge this does not differ between the OS's versions that are visible on the screenshots that you posted with your question, so as to exactly why this is happening is a bit of a mystery. My first guess is that this has something to do with the emulator and I would confirm this on actual devices with the respective OS versions.

**EDIT**

When supporting older OS versions you do indeed need to add both to your layout but to make sure that `marginStart` and `marginEnd` are used you need to set the `android:supportsRtl` attribute to **true**. Check out the first link I posted above for more information.

Comment: I know that end replaces right in API >=17 however I must keep the old one since I still support API14. In addition, I've tried this app on an actual Lollipop device and same as here, Lollipop ignores the new layout_marginEnd attribute.

Comment: Does anyone know if there will be a way to suck out all the duplication later when compat is not needed anymore? Kind of sucks to do it all 2x...

Comment: Lint will probably at least point you to the files as soon as you raise your min API level to 17 or above, but to remove it automatically you will probably have to revert to a command-line script.